# Apache & NGINX Redirects

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

How do I redirect to remove all intermediate folders between the domain name and the .html file name without explicitly adding multiple rules per redirect.

basically I want both:

> example.com/category/product.html 
>   example.com/category/sub-category/product.html

to redirect to

> example.com/product.html

I would also like:

> example.com/category/subcategory.html

to redirect to

> example.com/category.html

I don't have a logical way to differentiate between a subcategory.html and a product.html, so I am open to explicitly matching (or not matching) to list the sub-categories.

I would like to accomplish this for both apache and nginx styles of rewriting.

Comment: I was able to get /category/product.html to redirect correctly using RedirectMatch 301   "^/category(/.*)\.html$" "$1.html" But I cant handle the category/subcategory situation. It redirects those to subcategory/product.html

Comment: Do you have a logical way to differentiate between a `product.html` and a `subcategory.html`? For example, a `product.html` will only contain product ids or numerical only.

Comment: Good point, I dont think I can. Not one that is obvious to me at least. In that case I will need to specify the sub-categories explicitly. That isnt too bad, there's only about 5/6 of them and they are the same across the main categories. I will edit the main question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these regex in this order:

`^\/(category)\/(subcategory|subcategory2|subcategory3)\.html$` -> `/$1.html` for redirecting `example.com/category/subcategory.html` to `example.com/category.html`. [See Online](https://regex101.com/r/xPfGRi/1)

`^\/(category)\/.*?([^\/]+)\.html$` -> `/$2.html` for redirecting `example.com/category/product.html` or `example.com/category/sub-category/product.html` to `example.com/product.html`. [See Online](https://regex101.com/r/xPfGRi/3)

You can replace `category` and `subcategory` with actual values.

Comment: As long as they are in order they should work, right? because if the 1st regex doesn't execute first then the 2nd regex will encounter situations it will fail on.

Comment: btw, i think that regex testing site is fantastic! I wish I knew about it a while ago!

Comment: You got it, the order is the key here.